# Where is Google Earth Pro installed in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, settings, google-earth, joystick

I installed Google Earth Pro using the `.deb` package. Now I am struggling to find where it is installed. Where do `.deb` packages get installed in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Comment: The question in your body text does not seem to match your title. Please improve.

Comment: Why do you need to know where it is installed? If you know that, what would you do with this information?

Comment: @Pilot6 I need to change joystick settings and need to increase speed of the airplanes in its flight simulator.

Comment: How is related Google Earth and joystick?

Comment: @Pilot6 Google Earth **Pro** has a built-in flight simulator.

Comment: OK. And if you find the place, do you know how to increase joystick speed there?

Comment: `/opt/google/earth/pro/resources/flightsim/aircraft` is where the aircraft config files are stored. Modifying them has an effect on the speed. Here is also a video that shows what to change https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONLO5aBBvM0

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed place where deb files install stuff.

It depends on a deb file, what is written in its install scripts.

Regarding Google applications,  it is very likely  that they are installed under `/opt/google`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `/opt/google` is exactly where it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg-query -L <packagename>` will show you locations of all files installed from a given package.